# Weblogic 12c ear deployment

Tags: jstl, weblogic12c

I have a bunch of war files running on a Tomcat server. I packaged these files into an ear and I want to deploy it on Weblogic 12c Server. It seems that Weblogic try to precompile all the jsp contained in the package when i do the deploy. It gives me the following error:

```
Failure while precompiling JSPs: weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException:xxx.jsp:279:86: This attribute is not recognized.
<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="${xxx}" placeholder="${dateformat}"/></td>
                                                    ^---------^
```

I guess there is some problem with the jstl libraries. I followed this guide https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/configurejsfandjtsl.htm#WBAPP197 and I found out that Weblogic version i'm using should support Jstl natively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<fmt:formatDate>` tag is invalid. There is no `placeholder` in the tag. The `placeholder` attribute should be in the `input` tag instead. Your page should read something like this:

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="${xxx}" var="formattedDate" />
<input placeholder="${formattedDate}"/>
```

Nothing wrong with the `JSTL` libraries, rather a problem with your code. You probably didn't see this under Tomcat because you don't precompile the files there and haven't navigated to the page in question.